# MacBook для разработки под .net

Tags: .net, macos, monodevelop

Всю сознательную жизнь сидел на Windows, но сейчас появилась возможность и желание взять себе Mac Book, т.к. важна портативность и долгая работа от батареи.

Нашёл Visual Studio под Mac. https://www.visualstudio.com/ru/vs/visual-studio-mac/?rr=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.by%2F

Но так и не смог найти ответы на следующие вопросы:

1) Если у меня сейчас есть проект, написанный на Asp.NET в обычной VS под Windows, смогу ли я, используя VS под Mac продолжать работать с этим проектом?

2) Если 1-й пункт невозможен, то смогу ли я нормально работать с проектами, которые люди пишут на VS под Windows с помощью MonoDevelop?

3) Проигрывает ли в данный момент MonoDevelop Visual Studio? (задержками обновления компилятора, не сразу приходят новые версии языка, etc.)

Comment: Посмотрите ещё Rider, он весьма не плох.

Comment: Rider ещё очень сырой

Answer (score 1):

1. Нет, не сможете, на Mac будут работать только просекты написанные на .Net Core.
2. Нет
3. Проигрывает, так как MonoDevelop разрабатывает не Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю немного к ответу @Андрей-Бордюков:

1. На днях появилась Visual Studio for Mac. На самом деле это переделанная и доработанная Xamarin Studio, но в нее добавили ASN.NET Core Web App и .NET Core консольные приложения (и многое другое). Возможно вам хватит этих вариантов.
2. Есть прекрасный Parallels Desktop для MacOS, который позволяет работать (через виртуальную машину) с приложениями под Windows без проблем. Я замечал небольшое уменьшение времени работы macbook-а, но в целом можно спокойно работать с оригинальной Visual Studio для Windows. Он платный, но того стоит.